# PHP/.HTACCESS | Manually Set GET Variable To Stop Vanity URL Interference?

Tags: php, get, null

I want to set a $_GET variable if its empty. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is what I have so far.

```
if(!$_GET["profile"]) 
{
      $_GET["profile"] = null;  
}
```

**EDIT**

The whole reason I am trying to do this is because I have two vanity URL's set in my .htaccess, but I am trying to figure out how to skip the second vanity URL so I don't need to go to something.com/home/ <-- Note the second slash, if I don't put the second slash, then it directs me to my 404 error document. Basically, how do I allow it so I don't need to put the second slash, resulting in that GET variable being empty?

Here is my .htaccess,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&profile=$2 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /redir404.php
```

Like I said, for this to work, and not send me to my ErrorDocument, I need to set my URL's to be http://ncms.us/home/ for it to work.

Comment: How have you determined that it "isn't working"?

Comment: It's not clear how this variable relates to the "vanity URLs". `$_GET` gets parameters from after `?` in the URL, nothing to do with `/` (unless there's a rewrite rule in .htaccess that's doing this).

Comment: @Barmar, It was =] I just posted it.

Comment: Is your script even being run? I think you may need to add another rewrite rule to handle this case.

Comment: Or just mark the `/` in the RewriteRule as optional.

Comment: @Barmar, how do I make the / optional?

Comment: @Necro. - With a question mark: `/?`, you could also just make the whole second capturing group optional and put the slash in it, I believe (not 100% sure what you're doing on the backend or if this is correct): `^([^/]*)(/[^/]*)?$`.

Comment: Personally, I'd just route everything through index.php and let the application handle the errors and URL parsing, I'm not saying you *should*, but it's definitely an option.

Comment: @WesleyMurch ^([^/]*)(/[^/]*)?$ worked PERFECT. Now I just need to strip out / whenever I look for the $_GET["profile"], It adds a slash to the variable. You can see here, http://ncms.us/home/example But thank you anyway! This other problem is more of an annoyance anyway, it'd be nice if I can fix that, but awesome!

Comment: Yeah just use `trim($var, '/')` to get rid of those.

Comment: If you put `/?` in the regex, but outside the capture group, it won't show up in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar everything seems to be working. I'm echoing the $_GET variable, so its finding it all. I don't quite understand what you say is going to not work?

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work, I said taking the `/?` out of the capture group means you don't need to remove it in the PHP.

Answer (score 3):

First off, this line will generate an "undefined index" notice:

```
if ( ! $_GET["profile"])
```

It's better to use `isset()` to avoid these notices:

Secondly, your script should be working fine, but a variable with a value of `NULL` is actually *not* "set", which might be tripping you up:

```
if ( ! isset($_GET["profile"]))
{
    $_GET["profile"] = null;  
}
var_dump(isset($_GET["profile"])); // will print FALSE
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php 
>   isset — Determine if a variable is set **and is not NULL**

However, you can still use `$_GET["profile"]` while it has a `NULL` value in your script without it generating a notice.

It might be better to just create a new variable rather than read from `$_GET` directly:

```
$profile = isset($_GET["profile"]) ? $_GET["profile"] : NULL;
```

Injecting values into superglobals can sometimes have strange side effects in other scripts, since they have global access. It's best to avoid it.

Comment: OP should also look into the [`empty()`](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function as they are logically different concepts in PHP. Also, I agree on the bit about not modifying a `$_GET`/`$_POST` variable. The only 2 things you should do with it is read it into another variable/function, or `unset()` it.

Comment: I would not unset it either, personally. I prefer to use a wrapper class for read-only access superglobals, plus you can use convenience methods to fetch them. I would also beware of `empty` since it returns true on `(string) '0'` which can lead to bugs if you aren't aware of it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Please look at my edit. This should explain my goal more clearly.

Comment: Would you post your htaccess file's content? To be honest, your edit changes the scope of the question drastically, I would post it as a separate one - but this time, present the actual problem (vanity URLs / htaccess / 404s / $GET var you don't want) and ask for a solution. The technical question you originally asked has already been answered.

Comment: I did...People completely disregarded it =/ I thought if I had tried setting the GET variable it'd be fixed. I will post my .htaccess, and change the title.

Comment: @Necro: It's can be [considered rude](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) to do that as it invalidates existing answers, but I won't stop you.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Ah, alright...Sorry =/ I just kinda figured I was already here, and I honestly had a strictly only PHP question at first. Thank you for letting me know though.

Answer (score 0):

Use !isset($_GET["profile"]) to see if it's not set.

Comment: Well after checking if its set, how would I manually set the GET variable?

Comment: Regular assigment will work.  You just need to make sure that assignment is called, hence the use of isset.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

`empty( )` — Determine whether a variable is empty

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/|)([^/]*)$ /index.php?p=$1&profile=$3 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /redir404.php
```

This will rewrite the urls as follows:

```
example.com/home -> example.com/index.php?p=home&profile=
example.com/home/user -> example.com/index.php?p=home&profile=user
```

(I could not test the rewrite rules in a .htaccess file, but the Regex to parse the url should be correct)